# request a URL and parse the response in Python

Tags: python

I'm migrating a utility tool from Java to Python and I'm new to Python. I want to know the best way to do these simple and common tasks in Python:

1. Build a URL with all parameters encoded correctly(using UTF8).
2. Request the URL and parse the XML response.
3. Find any node with a tag name "Foo"
4. Find any node with a attribute Foo="Bar"

I need to do all these things using Python 2.7.3 API only (without any third-party module or library).

Comment: [Python URL fetching HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html), [Python XML HOWTOs](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Tutorials%20on%20XML%20processing%20with%20Python).

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) library for making the requests and [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) for parsing the responses.  They both come with Python 2.7.3.  For encoding the parameters, there's a method called `urlencode` which is part of the [urllib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) library (the original one in this case, not urllib2).

Comment: No, please, not the minidom. As it states on the documentation you linked to, use ElementTree instead.

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't done XML parsing in Python in a while.  I'll edit the answer to include ElementTree.